# sqlite database default time not getting correct value

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I use the following code

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  modifieddate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

but the default value i get in modifieddate column is ' 2014-03-18 00:00:00 '.

Date value is correct, but not getting the time value.

Comment: How are you inserting and reading the data?

Comment: yes, i insert data and then check the database.

Comment: Which SQLite version? Which operating system?

Comment: SQLite version - 3.6.20
OS - OS X 10.9.1

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     modifieddate DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
);
```

Comment: :( same issue - the default value i get is '2014-03-19 00:00:00'

Comment: ok, then try this: create table test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, modifieddate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);